# What is the origin of the phrase "something is fishy"

Tags: etymology

I have heard this phrase quite a few times and I am curious what is the origin of this phrase?

Comment: The phrase is usually *something smells fishy* and occasionally gets shortened.

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE! And, as the answerers mention, [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/) is an "exasperatingly" awesome source if you wanted to check for something's etymology. :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about etymology, which is suitable for [English.SE].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=fishy&searchmode=none) tells us:

> fishy (adj.)
>   late 15c., "fish-like, slimy," from fish (n.) + -y (2). In reference to taste, from 1540s. Sense of "shady, questionable" is first recorded 1840, perhaps from the notion of "slipperiness," or of giving off a bad odor.

So it either refers to the tendency of fish to be slippery, meaning they cannot be trusted to *not* slip out of your hands, or it refers to the notion that fish tend to start smelling after a while.

Since we also use the expression that *something smells fishy*, I would assume that the odour-link is the most likely: fish, and places where fish is sold, tend to be associated with bad smells.

Answer (score 5):

This is a reference to the fact that fish products do not smell bad until they begin to spoil, but may look completely fine.

In other words, something feels wrong in a way that isn't completely obvious.